# Why is my Token Not Searchable on Solana Explorer?

Tags: metadata, explorers, fungible-token

My token, aBion, was created two years ago. You can see it in the Solana Explorer here: https://explorer.solana.com/address/J3ts1ZEyQeUAbUyYHjZR6sE93YQTrfBzho8UKWnEa1j/metadata

In the past, typing "abion" into the Solana Explorer search bar would conjure up this token. However, recently, typing "abion" into the search no longer shows any results.

What is the reason for this change? Is it because the token's metadata isn't up-to-date with the latest metadata standards? Or is it because the token hasn't manually submitted for verification to the Solana Explorer staff? Or is it because the token has not had any transactions lately? Or is it just something else entirely?

I greatly appreciate your help in this. If you have any questions about the token, please let me know!